# Testing gevent-socketio on Django

Tags: django, gevent-socketio

I have a `django` site which uses `gevent-socketio` for a word game and I would like to automate the tests.

Since `gevent-socketio` implies user interaction and JavaScript actions I'm stuck in how to start writing tests.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: How about [selenium](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2012/nov/2/introduction-django-selenium-testing/)

Comment: @Hedde Didn't know about selenium, and it looks very interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some referrals:

- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Basically, it's testing in a real browser that django can integrate with by the help of [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).
- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) - programmatic web-browsing. It's a very powerful tool, definitely worth looking. Note that it can "talk" to javascript.
- [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) - testing tool that works using screenshots. Very powerful too, but may be a bit too exotic in your case.

Hope that helps.